# Post doesn't load after posting it

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I created a new post, but it will not show up after submitting it:

[image: First error message]
[Full screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roG5I.jpg)

This happened to me on a Nexus tablet.

**Edit:** On posting this post, the following error appeared:

[image: Second error message]
[Full screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoQuA.jpg)

Comment: Oh dear I read your post wrong. Sorry about the previous comment. I need a cup of coffee.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221705/158100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.85.

A full explanation is here: ["This question is not available, it may have been deleted" when submitting a question on the Android app after losing internet connection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245618/this-question-is-not-available-it-may-have-been-deleted-when-submitting-a-que/277404#277404)